# Problema/bug no fechamento de perguntas?

Tags: bug, status-intencional, fechamento

Hoje eu notei um comportamento no mínimo estranho com o sistema de votação para fechamento de perguntas.

Anteriormente eu **já havia votado** para fechar a pergunta [identificar formas geometricas basicas em imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138917/identificar-formas-geometricas-basicas-em-imagem) (que eu estou referenciando apenas porque pode ser útil para os moderadores analisarem o problema). Porém, hoje olhando-a novamente, não consta alí nenhuma indicação de que a pergunta contém votos para fechamento:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entrando novamente na opção de votar para fechar, o sistema de fato informa que eu já votei, e diz que eu posso reatribuir meu voto próximo do final do mês:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso se trata de algum recurso novo? Se sim, não está errado ele não informar na página principal da pergunta que ela contém votos para fechamento?

---

Today I found a weird behavior, to say the least, with the voting to close questions system.

I **had previously voted** to close the question [identificar formas geometricas basicas em imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138917/identificar-formas-geometricas-basicas-em-imagem). However, looking at it today, the question does not appear to show any votes for closure.

Clicking on the "close" button again, I am informed by the system that I have already voted, and that I can vote again at the end of the month.

Is this a new feature? If so, shouldn't it inform me in the question page that there are votes for closure in that question?

Comment: Eu acho que o voto expirou, mas como já votou, não pode votar de novo. Mas não tenho certeza que é isto. A mensagem ali em cima mostra isto. Dia 25 poderá votar novamente.

Comment: @bigown Não sabia que votos pra fechar expiravam. Ainda mais em uma semana. :/

Comment: Sim, expiram começando em 4 dias: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire se bem que neste caso parece que deveria ser 14 dias, sei lá se é *bug* nesse ponto. Ou se isto está desligado neste site.

Comment: @bigown Ah, ok. Obrigado pelo link. E então eis aí mais uma feature no sistema pra eu discordar.

Comment: @bigown interessante não fazia a menor ideia, e depois de expirarem todos os votos a pergunta sai da fila de analise?

Comment: @JorgeB. eu acho que sim.

Comment: Se vale como algum desabafo, [já não é de hoje](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4993/73) que o sistema gradualmente me desmotiva a ajudar na moderação. Bem triste isso. :/

Comment: @LuizVieira nisso concordo, ainda por cima agora com o sistema de "teste" modero muito menos o site. É bem verdade.

Comment: Luiz e @JorgeB., até um ano atrás os votos demoravam muito para expirar e ficavam pendurados para sempre na pergunta. Isso deixava a fila de fechamento cheia demais (principalmente no SOen, mas reparem que a nossa também está bem cheia mesmo com a expiração dos votos). Uma fila de análise gigante também desincentiva a moderação, pois parece que nunca será vencida. Vejam esta [minha postagem no MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252598/825789) na época. Dito isso, parece que seu voto expirou antes do que deveria, ou as regras aqui são diferentes, como disse o bigown. Vou verificar.

Comment: É um bom ponto de vista @bfavaretto, tenho de concordar.

Comment: @bfavaretto Compreendo e concordo. Mas isso só quer dizer que se deveria expirar *as perguntas da fila de análise*. Os votos pra fechar poderiam permanecer na pergunta sem mal algum (com a vantagem de facilitar o rastreamento das escolhas por parte da comunidade e do próprio participante).

Comment: @LuizVieira também não está mal visto, não senhor.

Comment: @LuizVieira mas vc ñ entende nada desse negócio de UX :P

Comment: Concordo que os votos expirados poderiam ser mais rastreáveis, mas continuo achando que votos pendurados por muito tempo não servem para muita coisa. É um registro de que alguém algum dia já considerou a pergunta fechável, mas a chance de ela acabar fechada cai bastante com o passar do tempo. E a fila foi criada com isso em vista, acabar com o backlog de perguntas penduradas. Então, se a conclusão for que é melhor nunca expirar os votos, a própria existência da fila passa a ser questionável.

Comment: @bfavaretto Bom, eu continuo achando que estamos misturando as coisas. No meu entendimento a fila existe para agilizar a tomada de ações atraindo *rápida e momentaneamente* a atenção da comunidade. Por outro lado, os votos existem para indicar problemas no conteúdo, e nesse sentido são bastante equivalentes às positivações/negativações. Ou seja, o fato de uma pergunta não ter sido fechada a tempo (ou ter sido fechada muito rapidamente) *não quer dizer* que ela deixa de ter problemas só com a passagem do tempo. Mas, é só a minha opinião. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O voto expirou por causa [desta análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/72264). Como um moderador votou para "deixar aberta," o voto expirou, conforme [o post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120902/208518) para onde [este comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5170/problema-bug-no-fechamento-de-perguntas#comment18748_5170) aponta diz:

> **Flag it for a moderator.** That's what they're there for: exception handling when the community can't act on its own. If they agree, no expiration rules apply to them: their close vote is binding.

Sendo que a parte relevante aqui é que **o voto de um moderador é vinculativo, e expira os outros votos existentes instantaneamente.**

Comment: Ok. Obrigado pela explicação. De fato, o comportamento do sistema faz sentido agora que você apontou esse detalhe importante (apesar de eu não concordar nem com o sistema, nem com o analista rs). :)